# using quotient and remainder operators to extract and print each digit

Tags: c#, console

Can anyone please give me some logic or hint of a C# program that initialize an integer variable n with the value 7658 and then uses the quotient and remainder operators to extract and print each digit of n.
I need just suggestions so that i can go on further.
I want to display it in a like: 
n= 7658
The digits of n  are 7, 6, 5,  and 8.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? What do you think you might want to divide by, for example?

Comment: i want to diplay the numbers in the format like:
 n= 7658 The digits of n are 7, 6, 5, and 8

Comment: Seems to be a homework. :)

Comment: @Leri...yes kind of....buti just need some hints.

Comment: @HaiderKhattak: Without evidence of *any* effort so far, this question really isn't appropriate.

Comment: Did you ask the same question a few minutes ago but...

Comment: @HaiderKhattak `7658 = 7*(10^3) + 6*(10^2) + 5*(10^1) + 8*(10^0)` This hint should be enough. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked the same question a few minutes ago.

We told you like *This is not a good way to ask a question in here* but anyway..

```
int i = 7658;
Console.WriteLine(i % 10); //Last digit.
i = i / 10;
Console.WriteLine(i % 10); //Third digit.
i = i / 10;
Console.WriteLine(i % 10); //Second gidit.
i = i / 10;
Console.WriteLine(i % 10); //First digit.
```

Logic is here;

1. `7658 % 10 = 8` (Gives the last digit) Take a look [`% Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)
2. Make [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with `10`
3. Continue to step 1 while number is bigger than `10`.

As a visual, I steal some part of [SWeko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721084/447156);

```
7658 % 10 = 8
765 % 10 = 5
76 % 10 = 6
7 % 10 = 7
```

Comment: i am not getting the use of 10

Comment: @HaiderKhattak Do you know [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)? The `%` operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second. So when you use `7658 % 10` reminder will be `8`

Comment: @HaiderKhattak As you know, `7658 = (765 * 10) + 8`

Comment: @GrantWinney
i have voted up for soner and told my colleagues and they have voted him up too. thanks soner & grant

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 7658;
Console.Write("the n are");
for(int a=0;a<=i;a++)
{
    Console.Write( i%10+",");
    i = i / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a short extension method like this:

```
public static class Helper {

    public static IEnumerable<int> EnumerateDigits(this int @this) {
        Stack<byte> stack = new Stack<byte>();
        do {
            var digit = (byte)(@this % 10);
            stack .Add(digit);
            @this /= 10;
        } while (@this != 0);

        while (stack .Count > 0)
            yield return stack.Pop();
    }

}
```

then, you could use that method, with any `int`, not just the number `7658`, like so:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
     int someNumber = ...

     foreach (var digit in someNumber.EnumerateDigits())
         Console.WriteLine(digit);

     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: This will however, return the digits in a reverse order, right-to-left.

Comment: That is correct @SWeko, thank you for noticing. Just made an edit to the extension method that puts the digits on a stack and the returns them in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

The reminder of a number divided by 10 is the last digit of that number:

```
7658 % 10 = 8
765 % 10 = 5
76 % 10 = 6
7 % 10 = 7
```

The quotient of a number divided by 10 are the digits of that number, except the last number:

```
7658 / 10 = 765
765 / 10 = 76
76 / 10 = 7
7 / 10 = 0
```

So you can loop until the given number is 0, and repeatedly extract the last digit, to get each digit separately.

---

To adress the OP's comment about the value of 10 used: since we use a [positional number-writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system#Positional_systems_in_detail), writing 7658 is basically shorthand for writing:

```
7 thousand, 6 hundred, 5 tens, and 8 units.
```

In the last statement, thousand is 1000, or 10 * 10 * 10, hundred is 100, or 10 * 10, ten is, not surprisingly 10, and units is 1 (mathematically speaking, it's 10 multiplied [zero times with itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_power#Arbitrary_integer_exponents)), so 7658 is:

```
7 X 10^3 + 6 X 10^2 + 5 ^ 10 + 8, or
(((7 * 10) + 6) * 10 + 5) * 10 + 8
```

The last formula is used in the code.

Incidentally, if you replace 10 with, let's say, 16, you will get an algorithm for converting a number to the hexadecimal system, or if you replace it with 2, you'll get the binary digits of the number.

Comment: `+1` for stealing some part of your answer `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public  void SpillInt(){
        int n = 7658;

        int remainder = 0;
        int divider = 10;

        IList<int> result = new List<int>();
        do
        {
                   remainder = n % divider;
            result.Add(remainder);
            n = (n - remainder) / 10;
        }
        while (n > 0);
                    for (int i = result.Count; i >= 0; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(result[i]);
        }
}
```